# Using the output of the shader as a masking factor in the cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, node-editor, shaders

[image]

I use the output of the material(shader) as a masking factor in the Blender Internal renderer.

I tried to do the same in Cycles but it didn't work.

Is it possible to use only texture or input nodes as a masking source in Cycles? Or am I making the wrong nodetree?

What I'm worried about is that when Blender Interal is completely replaced by EEVEE and disappears from Blender, the way I use it is useless.

I would like to ask you if there is something I know wrong or if there is another implementation method.

Thank you.

The image below is a close-up capture of the node I made.

[image]

Comment: It's not quite clear what your ultimate goal is, so it's hard to come up with other ways of doing the same thing. I suspect you'll find some usefulness in the dot product of the geometry normal and the vector to the camera. If the dot product of those two angles is 0, then the normal is pointing perpendicular to the camera. If the dot product is 1, then the normal is pointing directly at the camera. Use a Ramp to blend between 0-1. Maybe something similar with the angle to a lamp instead of the camera. More info would help.

Comment: If, on the other hand, what you're actually after is the final color of the surface, you'll likely have to do that in post. The shader doesn't have a way to know the final color in the image.

Comment: Okay, my final goal is shell shading.
BI can use the shadow border as a masking factor and can directly specify the color of both sides.
Cycles' Toon shader does not look like that. Guilty Gear Xrd, who is rated the ultimate NPR art style in the current production interview, shows that they uses a separate map to compensate for the color of dark areas for more beauty. BI, on the other hand, is very intuitive because it does not need a map.

Comment: Normal Editing is now possible in Blender due to 'User Normal Translator' or 'Blend4Web'. In addition, the intuitive coloring of BI and the fast pace of OpenGL rendering make it a great combination for creating NPR-style footage. When BI disappeared due to EEVEE, I hope EEVEE or Cycles will do the same, but it seems difficult at this time.
tell me your opinions please.